# php session_start() function taking too much time in YII App

Tags: php, session, yii, memcached, couchbase

I have a yii app running on server. Some of URL's are taking time to load (34 sec), on further debugging i found php session_start function took around 32 sec and rest script gets executed in less than 2 sec.

There are many request where session_start() is the only culprit. I searched on net and every one suggests it is something related

- to session file handling of php (change it to DB and issue will get resolve)
- use session_write_close() after data is set in session.

But in my case Session is getting stored in couchbase, so first points does not seems to be valid. Can any one suggest the exact usage of session_write_close(), as data being is set in script at various location.

If any one has faced similar issues, please help

Any help would be greatfull.

Comment: I would start by looking at couchbase, or the network from code to db for bottle necks and or look at you couchbase config.

Comment: Thing is there no custom code to set data in couchbase (memcache), we have set session handler in php.ini and rest is handled by php itself i.e during session_start() php a) opens the session and b) reads session. So you are saying there is something realted to couchbase and not php code?

Comment: Right, so look at the infrastucture between the code execution and the round trip from there to the couchbase database server

Comment: Can it be something related to Couchbase (memcache) memory allocation etc. Can you please be more specific what things i need to check on couchbase side. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, dont know, I have never used it. It just looks like the most likely place to start.You are going to have to trace the process through all the intermediate servers